# Anderson Darling test doesn't show the normality of the data

Tags: matlab

I have an array and I need to know if the data is normally distributed (increasing and then decreasing)or not? and if so what is the percentage of normal distribution in the data? 
I used the Anderson-Darling goodness-of-fit hypothesis test but it says that the data below is not normally distributed and I am wondering why? .. any help? 
4   9   16  28  45  94  159 193 232 239 229 218 186 142 94  57  31  12  8   3   1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Statistics, not programming. Consider moving it to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: "Normal distribution" does not just mean "increasing then decreasing". If you want help on your MATLAB code, show us the code (how you implemented the test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of numbers doesn't look like a normally distributed set of numbers. That looks like the number of occurences of your original (potentially normally distributed) data. The list you've given includes mostly low and high numbers and little around 100. Use `hist` to show the distribution of the supplied data. Use `adtest` with your original data.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but what if I need to know if the array is increasing and then decreasing? and if there is any inconsistency which means that there are some values which makes the array values not increasing and then decreasing?

Comment: That seems to be a different issue which has little to do with whether it is normally distributed. But; use 'diff' to see if the difference between numbers is positive or negative. If you take the 'diff' again on the 'sign()' you get what you wanted to know (you expect all zeros with one -2 at the changeover). For your data: diff(sign(diff(x))) = [0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    -2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0].

Comment: Btw, I disagree with Luis Mendo, the question is not about the working of the hypothesis test itself, but with his/her implementation in Matlab - although it may read as such. (my rep. is too low to comment on the original question).

Comment: Thanks a lot A.Klomp .. I got your idea and it worked fine,
thanks again